# RxJava2: emit item before observable disposed

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

How can I emit an item just before my observable stream gets disposed?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#1.8), you shouldn't emit an item knowing that the subscription has been cancelled:

> If a Subscription is cancelled its Subscriber MUST eventually stop being signaled.

So there is no way of doing it with the library, unless you implement your own ObservableOperator.